# PyQt5: убрать задний фон кнопки QPushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qpushbutton

Существует кнопка `PushButton` c текстом "**?**" как на картинке (правый верхний угол):

[image]

Нужно полностью убрать ее задний фон, то есть от кнопки должен остаться только "**?**".

Было бы здорово, если это можно сделать из `Qt Designer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос картинкой - ответ картинкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Установите свойство **flat** в инспекторе. Можно ещё с помощью кода:

```
PushButton.setFlat(True)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но правда я в вопросе указал pyqt5. тогда правильно будет ```PushButton.setFlat(True)```

Comment: Ойййй. Извините